# GlassFish can't find my datasource

Tags: jpa, glassfish, datasource, derby

I created a Java EE web application in NetBeans which is connected to a derby DB.

I generated a entity bean via "create entity from database" which i did.
There was a menu where i had to fill in the datasource which I called "WWHY Source".
After that I generated the session beans for the entity user.

The problem now is that each time I try to deploy my application it gives me an exception.

Initially during the deployment.

```
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Nam\Documents\Programming\NetBeansProjects\WWHY\build\web
GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, null, false
C:\Users\Nam\Documents\Programming\NetBeansProjects\WWHY\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
```

In the Glassfish log

```
Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : WWHY Source__pm
```

Honestly I don't have a single clue why it doesn't work.
I can give you the rest of glassfish log but the output is kinda the same.
I already tried clean and build, restarting netbeans but nothing helps.
It stopped working as soon as I tried to use JPA.

Please help me :)

---

**EDIT** 
When I created an Entity Bean via "Entity Class from Databases", it will automatically create a persistence.xml . I called the new Datasource "WWHY source":

```
<persistence-unit name="WWHYPU" transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source>WWHY Source</jta-data-source>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties/>
```

But the deploy somehow doesn't work because Glassfish searches for **"WWHY Source_pm"**

When I look into the JDBC Resources via GlassFish Console then there is no JDBC Resource with the name "WWHY Source".

Here is also the glassfish-resources.xml

```
<resources>
<jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="derby_net_WWHY-DB_rootPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
    <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="portNumber" value="1527"/>
    <property name="databaseName" value="WWHY-DB"/>
    <property name="User" value="root"/>
    <property name="Password" value="root"/>
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/WWHY-DB"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="WWHY Source" object-type="user" pool-name="derby_net_WWHY-DB_rootPool"/>
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks !

Comment: Did you create a JDBC resource after creating a connection pool? The JDBC resource name (the one you create using GlassFish Admin Console) must match the value under the `<jta-data-source>` section (`<jta-data-source>jdbc/pool</jta-data-source>` or whatever the name you choose) in your `persistenceContext.xml` file. You need to create a JDBC resource corresponding to connection pool and mention that name in `persistenceContext.xml` and this is off-topic for JSF. It has whatsoever nothing to do with the said problem. You would encounter the exact same problem even though you did not use JSF.

Comment: Well it does match but i delete it from the Glassfishserver again. Because Netbeans shows me the same JDBC resource twice and i'm really getting frustrated. I tried doing the exact same thing as in a tutorial video which i can't find anymore .... I'm going to start it over again and describe my problem more precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create a datasource directly in Glassfish server and then just update the name of your newly created data-source in your persistence.xml. Also I would recommend to create data-source name without a "space" (glassfish can go sometimes crazy from empty spaces).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me a lot !!! I just created a JDBC Connection Pool and after that a JDBC Resource and used them for creating the Entity Bean ("Create Entity Class from Database ---> choose Data Source). I would like to rate your answer but im just too new to Stack Overflow :D